# In react I want two buttons opening same modal but operation of both button is different

Tags: mysql, node.js, reactjs

I have two pages modal and welcome component
On modal component I have form with input fields and on welcome component I have two buttons add and edit details on click of add there should be open modal having input fields and on click of save button the details should be added in database and same for edit button on click of edit same modal should be open having details and user can edit those details

Comment: Hi! The guide at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, will help you improve your question and get helpful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like this work?

```js
function App() {
  const [modalOpen, setModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [item, setItem] = useState();
  const itemToEdit = {
    // Some properties - perhaps also stateful and selected from a list.
  }

  function handleAdd() {
    setItem({});
    setModalOpen(true);
  }

  function handleEdit() {
    setItem(itemToEdit);
    setModalOpen(true);
  }

  return <>
    <Modal isOpen={modalOpen} item={item} />
    <button onClick={handleAdd}>Add</button>
    <button onClick={handleEdit}>Edit</button>
  </>
}
```

Comment: It's passed in as a prop to the modal (`item={item}`). In the modal component you'd access it from the `props` object as described here: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: In my modal component I have form having input tag I have to access that input so can I use there props?? And I want to pass that values in database also

Comment: That's extending quite a bit beyond the scope of your original question. I'd recommend reading up on working with forms in react (https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) and using something like the built-in fetch api (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) or axios (https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) for server-side communication.